# Why css won't apply changes?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when I try to import css from folder. When I change something in css file, it just won't apply changes. When I try it inside the folder where is my php file, it works well.

If I delete everything in css file it just don't do anything. Like the file is saved and anything I do it won't apply any changes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/moj.css">
```

Comment: read about *cache*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Shift when you reload. That will clear the cache and load the new CSS changes.
It is a rookie problem. Happy Coding.

Comment: Actually this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go into inspect element mode, and right click on refresh button (Chrome) and click "Empty cache and hard reload" .
This fixed my problem!

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried pasting the whole URL (i.e. http://www.). I've found this to work sometimes when it is having trouble pulling the style sheet from another directory. Hope this helps!